# HTML email newsletter issue in Hotmail

Tags: html, css, newsletter, email-client, hotmail

I have the following html which works for me for all email client, but in hotmail i am getting some extra space between each html tags. Basically the spacing between tags are weird. I am using this html for example. it should look same as in browser. no extra space.

Anyone please help!!!

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="display:block;line-height:100%;">
                <tr>
                  <td style="color: #333332; font-family: Georgia, Times, serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px; text-align: justify;margin:0;">
                    Peakview Place Apartments in Englewood  CO are 25 minutes from downtown Denver and less than 5 minutes from I 25   Apartments have washers dryers  
                    private patios balconies  kitchens with pantries  wood burning fireplaces  large closet space and wood style floors in select homes   Pet friendly 
                    community features 24 hour fitness center  swimming pool  playground  barbecue picnic area and complimentary coffee   Located near the Denver Tech Center  
                    less than 10 minutes from Park Meadows Mall and less than five miles from C 470 and I 225   Call or visit our website for a personal tour                      
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>

              <table width="100%" border="0" style="color: #333332; font-family: Georgia, Times, serif; font-size: 14px;display:block;line-height:100%;">
                <tr>
                  <td style="color: #333332; font-family: Georgia, Times, serif; font-size: 14px;text-align: left;">
                    <strong>Floorplans &amp; Prices</strong>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="color: #333332; font-family: Georgia, Times, serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 22px;">
                  We offer pricing and floorplans to meet our resident's needs.  Click on one of the floorplan buttons below to see diagrams.
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
```

Comment: do you want this type of output? http://jsfiddle.net/LCn7x/

Comment: you might need to submit some screenshots of how it looks in Hotmail. can't picture your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the gap is happening in between your tables, try putting this in your header: `p {margin: 1em 0;}`

Another option is to use one big table instead of separating them.

Also, you forgot the `cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"` in your bottom table